# How to display only certain Series Groups on a chart in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am currently creating an SSRS report to show some statistics on VMs. There are several charts that each show statistics about the Clusters. Each cluster comes in pairs, and I want the graph to only show values based on which element of the pair they belong in.

For example, see the chart below:

[image: Current SSRS Graph]

I want to have this chart split into two, one that shows the line of Cluster that have "GB" at the end of their name, and another for the "SP"

I have in my datasets the value that could distinguish them, but I basically want to only display a line if it belongs to a certain subset of all the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list item with a group.

The group expression should be set to something like `=Right(Fields!server.Value,2)`

Now place the chart inside the list item. The group will create a distinct chart for each combination of the last 2 characters of server name

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! I just removed a prior comment because I realized I did not place it in a List object.

Comment: Do you know how I can make them appear side by side, rather than on top of one another?

Comment: Use tablix and create a column group